# NgRx ViewModel confusion

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, probably I am missing something fundamental, but I have the following dilemma:

1. I am receiving a list of items from my backend, similar to:

   ```
   interface Item {
     id: number;
     userId: number;
     categoryId: number;
   }
   ```
2. I also get a list of users and categories and keep them in my store:

   ```
   interface User {
     id: number;
     name: string;
   }

   interface Category {
     id: number;
     name: string;
   }
   ```
3. I want to derive an ItemVM view model using these three classes, which will store the derived data:

   ```
   interface ItemVM {
     id: number;
     userName: string;
     categoryName: string;
   }
   ```

My understanding is that I should create a selector like:

```
// map userId and categoryId to user.name and category.name
export const selectItemViewModel = createSelector(

  // get users, categories, and items
  selectUsers,
  selectCategories,
  selectItems,

  // map them
  (users, categories, items) => {
    return items.map(i => <ItemVM>{
      id: i.id,
      userName: users.find(u => u.id === i.userId).name,
      categoryName: categories.find(c => c.id === i.categoryId).name,
    });
  }

);
```

But what I don't understand is, since this selector is not an observable, how do I make sure that users, categories and items are already loaded when this is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors are pure functions (with some memoization going on) of the single source of truth state, viewable via a browser extension Redux DevTools.

If you care about `loaded` add it to the state per entity.

Following uses latest v15.2.1 @ngrx/entity

##### Example of Item entity state, repeat per entity

---

actions

```
export const apiActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Item/API',
  events: {
    'Load Items': emptyProps(),
    'Load Items Success': props<{ items: Item[] }>(),
    'Load Items Failure': props<{ error: string }>()
  },
});
```

reducer

```
export interface ItemsState extends EntityState<Item> {
  loaded: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Item> = createEntityAdapter<Item>();

const initialState: ItemsState = adapter.getInitialState({
  // set initial required properties
  loaded: false
});

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  ...
  on(apiActions.loadItemsSuccess, (state, { items }) =>
    adapter.setAll(items, { ...state, loaded: true })
  ),
  ...
);

export const itemsFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'items',
  reducer
});

// register via StoreModule.forFeature(itemsFeature)
```

selectors

```
export const {
  // selector for each feature state property
  selectEntities,
  selectLoaded
} = itemsFeature;
```

---

Then compose a multi feature selector

```
import { selectLoaded as selectItemsLoaded } from '<path>/items.selectors.ts';
import { selectLoaded as selectUsersLoaded } from '<path>/users.selectors.ts';
import { selectLoaded as selectItemsLoaded } from '<path>/categories.selectors.ts';

export const selectItemVmLoaded = createSelector(
  selectItemsLoaded,
  selectUsersLoaded,
  selectItemsLoaded,
  (l1, l2, l3) => ({ l1 && l2 && l3 })
)
```

`selectItemVmLoaded` can be added into your selector as an easy way to know whether to just return [] and wait for the api calls.

You can expose in service as, eg. for showing a spinner / skeleton conponents

```
  itemVmLoaded$ = this.store.select(selectItemVmLoaded);
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Worth adding v15.2 added extraSelectors to createFeature which exposes the selectAll selector to simplify getting array of items from the store. See https://twitter.com/MarkoStDev/status/1618693389272379393

Answer (score 0):

It's a selector which use a distinctUntilChange() and it will be initialized at the bootstrap by the initial state of each reducer so initialize with an empty array not with null ;)

so what you do is correct and everything is fine here.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the items are loaded but not the users/categories

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? there is a initial state

Comment: See OP's code, `categories.find(c => c.id === i.categoryId).name`...if categories not loaded

Comment: just need to protect it `categories.find(c => c.id === i.categoryId)?.name` but i understand what you mean

Comment: possible but I'd guess most applications wouldn't want the items view model to emit possibly 3 times in quick succession as items, users and categories arrive

Comment: To avoid that use the debounce selector: https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/read#debounce-selectors


It's better than manage flag by hand